# What is the best way to implement a buffer for a text edit control?

Tags: c++, winapi

So i am making a custom edit control. In order to keep track of the contents of the edit control, I'm using a dynamically allocated char array.

- Now, I know that I need to insert in the middle of the array in
  certain situations, such as when the user clicks on a particular
  point. So, I was thinking, instead of a character array, I may use
  std::vector, so i would be able to use the .insert function, and also
  wouldn't have to care much about the memory management.
- I was also thinking maybe to directly store the input stream into an
  array/vector of words(Without keeping a continuous buffer), since my
  whole purpose with this is to implement syntax highlighting.

Which would be a better approach to go about things? And why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a text buffer with today computers you can indeed just use a single contiguous buffer (e.g. a vector) because CPUs are fast enough to make insertion time (an `o(n)` operation with this naive approach) still a viable option.

In the past when computers were thousands times slower a common simple approach was instead to keep the text in a buffer but with an "hole" corresponding to the cursor position, to make insertion an `o(1)` operation and moving chars from one side of the hole to the other when cursor was moving in the text (basically making cursor movement an `o(k)` operation where `k` is the number of skipped chars).

For an editor designed for programmers the text is going to be subdivided in logical lines and therefore using an approach based on an array of pointers to lines seems appropriate. Even if this will make some cross-line operation somewhat annoying some of line-based operations will become easier... line numbering in display becomes a trivial problem, especially if you don't need to implement line wrap (horrible with code anyway) by going for truncation and horizontal scrolling instead.

Comment: Thats a very nice explanation, thanks! Yeah, the text is going to be divided into logical lines, and I'm going with horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Editors which use one contiguous buffer suffer horribly when editing massive files (such as a log file). For source files it is fine, but people inevitably want to load _everything_ in their editor. Thus some kind of segmentation is required.

Answer (score 4):

The best approach is to start from the system edit or richedit control and adapt it to your needs. Writing your own edit control is way more work than you can possibly realise - including handling accessibility, IMEs for languages with complex alphabets, copy and paste, scroll bars, cursors, selections and lots more.

The two system controls provide lots of extension points that should allow you to achieve most goals. Unless you are really building a word process or source code editor, you should stick with the ones provided. And custom edit controls are a massive source of bugs. I seldom see one that works right just for the basic cases.

Martyn

Comment: I am building a source code editor. I already tried richedit and subclassing it is not as fast as I'd like it to be. I used over-write and setcharformat method, but they weren't very neat, so as to speak. I've started on my custom edit control, and I've already implemented the cursor and multi-line input. So, now I'm trying to make it ready for text selection and multi-line selection and stuff

Comment: If you are really building a source code editor, then implementing your own buffer is the right idea. Most source code editors get asked to load very large files (e.g. server logs), so make sure you think hard about the big O scalability of basic operations.

Answer (score 3):

If you are considering something like a source code viewer (ref: "to implement syntax highlighting") with a mutable backing store, you may find `std::list<std::string>` a good starting point, and it may be overkill if the string is small.

With a contiguous buffer for your text (e.g. one big `std::string` or `std::vector`), you will have a lot of moving and resizing during editing, as well as a lot of scanning when repositioning. Those moves and resizes will result in many large, contiguous allocations, initialization of the buffer, moving, and freeing of old memory. It also restricts how you cache data (if that is important). Your lookup times will be slightly slower with a list, but your moves and mutations will be much faster than using a contiguous buffer for the entire file.

`std::list<std::string>` has some nice properties because it grows and mutates as a collection of strings (e.g. for each line or paragraph) nicely.

This overview details the list's strengths and compares it to other containers well: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/

If you want to associate some data to the string/line, then just create a list of these:

```
namespace MON {
class t_line {
public:
  /* ... */
private:
  std::string d_string;
  t_lexer_stuff d_lexerStuff;
};
}
```

Answer (score 3):

While searching for the same thin I came across two Wikipedia pages that where very helpfull:

[Gap buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gap_buffer) for simple editing

[Rope (data structure)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28data_structure%29) for complex text editing

Comment: My attempt at a gap buffer in cpp: https://github.com/cmaughan/gapbuffer

Answer (score 2):

You might need a dual representation, so have both a vector of char and a vector of words (the issue is to keep them in sync).

I suggest also looking, and perhaps even using, some graphical toolkit whose source is freely available, and which can be customized. (I'm not a Windows guy, but) I was thinking e.g. of [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) which is an open-source graphical library in C++ running on Windows, Linux, MacOSX, ...

I cannot help more, because I don't know and I don't use Windows (all my machines are under Linux).

Comment: Thanks for the response man! I definitely will look into them once I have my own thing done. I want to get to know all the "under the hood" stuff first. I was also thinking that there might be a need for dual representation. Would this have a hit on the performance/memory usage? 
And how about keeping an vector of chars, and a vector of positions of each word? Like the start position and the length(using a structure)? Would that be better performance wise?

Comment: **premature optimization is evil** so first code a correct implementation, benchmark it using a profiler, and then optimize it

Comment: Actually, I just want to get a view of where I should be going with the code, so that I don't end up wasting time when it could have been easily avoided by choosing the correct approach to the problem

Comment: @Basile, choosing the right data representation is not a premature optimisation. If you blindly choose a data structure and algorithm you could easily find yourself with a system which _cannot_ work.